# include button into .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to read a text file containing the name of the image, and display it opon pageload.

Let's say that the content in the text file is

```
Australia    Picture101
Singapore    Picture201
```

Following is the code i tried and it does not display the image.

```
tableString += "<table class='content_background'  cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {   
            string[] country = line.Split(token2);
            string[] image = country[1].Split(token);
            string row = "<tr><td class='left_content'>" + country[0] + "</td>" +"<td><table><tr>";

            tableString += row;
            for (int i = 0; i < image.Length; i++)
            {
--->            string row2 = "<td class='right_content'> <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl='~/img/missing children pictures/" + "image[i]" + ".jpg'/>" + "</td>";

                tableString += row2;
            } 

            tableString += "</tr></table></td>";
        }

        tableString += "</tr></table>";

        container.InnerHtml = tableString;
```

Is there any other way to do this ? Thanks in advance.

the screen shot is as follow
[image: screen shot]

Comment: That's not how ASP.NET works, use a repeater instead, or if you want something more that style, try ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's no button ! You're outputting non-parsed HTML - the ASP.NET engine does not parse that, it just sends the data as HTML to the client.

Instead, use

```
var btn = new ImageButton();    
btn.ImageUrl = "~/img/missing children pictures/" + "image[i]" + ".jpg";
Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
```

As an easy hack, you can use

```
string row2 = "<td class=\"right_content\"> <input type=\"button\" style=\"background:url('/img/missing%20children%20pictures/" + image[i] + ".jpg')\"/></td>";
```

Comment: Hey thanks! 
using your way does get the image button out . but the image[i] could not be displayed still..

Comment: @foomingxiang I've corrected the 'hack', as the relative reference (~) isn't understood by a browser the same as the server understands it.

Comment: tried altering the hack , but it seems like it still couldnt retrieve the image.

Comment: @foomingxiang, SORRY, I've fixed it again. I had "image[i]" quoted (as literal HTML) when it shouldn't have been.

Comment: now i got it , but the problem now is that the picture cant be shown in full size . where only PART of the picture can fit into that button.

Comment: @foomingxiang, add "background-size: 100% auto;" to the style.

Comment: @freedompeace, all works!!! thank you so much!! and i have an extra question tho. what is i would wan to include .png file also?

Comment: @foomingxiang If you only have jpg and png files, use an if statement. If you have more than that, consider revising your code so that the extension is left in the images[] array, then just remove the extension part of the code (remove `+ ".jpg"`) and have the file extension in the images array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate HTML directly, then use HTML tags:

```
<a href="[Img_CLick Link]"><img src="[image path]"
  alt="Click" border="0" /></a>
```

Put appropriate values in the square brackets.

Otherwise consider using asp:Table control and add rows/cells at run time.